Intellij Encode HTML special characters: not working
Intellij Encode HTML special characters: not working.
Html editor:
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

Select the text, and then click
Edit > Encode XML/HTML special characters

Nothing happened.
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3 (Community Edition)

Please contact IntelliJ IDEA support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731 and share your IDE logs collected via Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data A couple of screenshots or a short screencast may also help to better understand your steps

I couldn't reproduce the problem in build 2024.2 Beta. Please try updating the IDE to the latest build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion

If Encode XML/HTML special characters isn't working then:

Ensure you've selected the text you want to encode
Confirm the file is recognized as HTML
Make sure IntelliJ IDEA is up to date
Check if the keymap for the action is correctly set
Verify that necessary HTML/XML plugins are enabled
Try File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
Look for errors in Help > Show Log


upgraded to latest 2024.1 version. did not help. any additional plugin needed for this? thanks

This looks like AI generates answer.

Try reinstalling IntelliJ IDEA again
